# How To Toggle Between Two Images With One Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I have a background on my body. The picture change into another one bothering on when it's night or day. But I need to have a "fast forward button" that change the theme/background even though it's not the right time of day.

Basically I need to be able to toggle between the two pictures with the press of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example of how I would do it here:
http://www.codeply.com/go/MvmYtciu10

With regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough.

Define an event to the click of the button on your client code.

When the event fires, change the src attribute of your image element depending on it's current value.